# Access data-href in backend code in c#

Tags: c#, html, .net

How to change the value of data-href in dotnet code behind Approach. Please i want to write different value in datahref attribute using query string

`<div class="fb-comments" id="abc" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Khaanaabaadosh" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light" runat="server"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

In your C# code, you should be able to do

```
abc.Attributes["data-href"] = "your custom link";
```